# RRule and iCal Complex recurrence

Tags: icalendar, eventkit, rrule

I need to be able to create events based on weekdays regardless of year. A good example would be Thanksgiving, the 4th Thursday in November:

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=Th;
BYMONTHDAY=22,23,24,25,26,27,28
```

But suppose I want the Sunday after Thanksgiving? It would be much the same, except when Thanksgiving falls on the 28th the following Sunday is in December. I tried:

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11,**12**;BYDAY=Su;
BYMONTHDAY=25,26,27,28,29,30,**01**
```

And this does not work, because it'll flag Sunday 11/1s and Sunday 12/25-30 as well.

Comment: The only solution I can come up with is to create a second event that handles dates that cross month boundaries. But that's not a very satisfying solution.

Comment: Another example of a complex recurrence I have to generate. The town's parade is always on the 2nd Saturday of December. The tree lighting and open house are on the preceding Fri and Sat, respectively. Fri and Saturday are not necessarily the first Fri and Sat of the month, they could be the last Fri in Nov and the first Sat of Dec.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of rules imply calculations that haven't been built into the iCal format, so it might not be possible for all rules of the mentioned kind to be modeled in iCal. Nevertheless it's often possible to find some 'workarounds' for specific cases, which is the case for the examples you mentioned:

The Sunday after the 4th Thursday of November:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYYEARDAY=-37,-36,-35,-34,-33,-32,-31;BYDAY=SU
```

The Saturday preceding the 2nd Saturday of December (i.e. the 1st Saturday of December):

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=12;BYDAY=1SA
```

The Friday preceding the 1st Saturday of December:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYYEARDAY=-32,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26;BYDAY=FR
```

The 1st Saturday of December AND the preceding Friday:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYYEARDAY=-32,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25;BYMONTH=11,12;BYDAY=-1FR,1FR,1SA;BYSETPOS=1,2
```